# Submitting R scripts with command_line_arguments to PBS HPC clusters

Tags: r, pbs

please could you advise me on the following : I've written a R script that reads 3 arguments from the command line, i.e. :

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
TUMOR <- args[1]       
GERMLINE <- args[2]
CHR <- args[3]
```

when I submit the R script to a PBS HPC scheduler, I do the following (below), but ... I am getting an error message.
(I am not posting the error message, because the R script I wrote works fine when it is run from a regular terminal ..)

Please may I ask, how do you usually submit the R scripts with command line arguments to PBS HPC schedulers ?

```
qsub -d $PWD -l nodes=1:ppn=4 -l vmem=10gb -m bea -M tanasa@gmail.com \
-v TUMOR="tumor.bam",GERMLINE="germline.bam",CHR="chr22" \
-e script.efile.chr22 \
-o script.ofile.chr22 \
 script.R
```

Comment: please post your error message ... I'm a little confused, I don't see where you actually specify the R executable?

Comment: Dear Ben, thank you for your message, will get back in a little while. The R script "script.R" is at the bottom of the qsub submission .